# Powerbuilder 2017 with Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, powerbuilder

How can I implement TFS in Powerbuilder 2017 ??
Do i need VisualStudio?

The goal is to use TFS for version control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps in brief

1. Setup the [team explorer 2013](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=team%20explorer%202013) (use this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) if you do not have visual studio subscription to download team explorer 2013 ) in the machine you are running PowerBuilder to get the TFS connectivity capability to your machine. You do not need to install Visual Studio.
2. [Install MSSCCI provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M) in the machine to allow power builder to access TFS version control
3. Create a team project in team foundation server
4. Connect Power Builder workspace to TFS by going to Properties of workspace and source control. Set the TFS as source control and provide the credentials to connect.

For more details you can follow the instructions in https://community.appeon.com/groups/powerbuilder/using-powerbuilder-2017-tfs-source-control

Comment: The link say Team explorer 2013 and there is a link to download but it's doesn't work. I only have visual studio explorer 2017

Comment: @MarcoMireles added a new link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785 if you do not have VS subscription to download team explorer. Or you can find all old versions here https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/ (for this link create Microsoft account or login from Microsoft account to download with minimum Dev Essential subscription)

Comment: @Marco Mireles I have a copy in OneDrive, you can download the team explorer 2013 from here : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7qD1NqycgBkn50Xhti_9EPRgZE

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Thank you :)